# Deleting an element of an array within a for loop - problem with the for loop skipping the next entry

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

To continue on from the title, I am deleting an element of an array within a for loop - the problem is the fact that the for loop then goes on to read the next element. Because (for example) array number 20 is deleted, 21 becomes 20 and so in the next loop of the for loop, 20 (previously 21) is now skipped...!

In more detail:
I have a for loop, within it I access the corresponding element of array[i], there is a statement in the loop that deletes that entry of the array if it fits a condition (don't worry about what the condition is).

```
for(i=0;i<total;++i)
{
    // if something is true (don't worry about what), the total reduces by 1.
    // then, in order to 
}
```

My problem is that when that element of the array is deleted in another for loop, the previous for loop will skip what was once the element after because it is now in the place of the element that has just been covered in the previous for loop.

```
for (int c = i; c < totaltri; c++)
{
    trilist[c] = trilist[c+1];
}
```

I know it's rather confusing but I've done my best to explain, I'm hoping that someone has a workaround...!

Comment: just start at the end and go backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
for(i=0;i<total;++i)
{
    if (delete_i'th_element)
    {
        --total;
        for (int c = i; c < total; c++)
        {
            trilist[c] = trilist[c+1];
        }
        --i;  // Decrement i to compensate for the increment in outer loop
    }
    else
    {
        ... other code
    }
}
```

An alternative approach:

```
i = 0;
while(i<total)
{
    if (delete_i'th_element)
    {
        --total;
        for (int c = i; c < total; c++)
        {
            trilist[c] = trilist[c+1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ... other code

        ++i;  // Increment i when the i'th element is processed
    }
}
```

Comment: But won't this skip trilist[c+1] (which has now become c) because the loop has just completed the cycle for that index of the array?

Comment: Do you see my problem? :)

Comment: Manipulating the loop index in the loop body might be confusing. I would suggest to use a `while` loop instead and increment the index only when necessary.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thank you @Bodo
I just don't see how I could implement this for loop as a while loop

Comment: @Bodo Using a `while` doesn't IMO make anything much different. You'll then have a branch with an increment an a branch without. And still you'll need to modify `total` which is also a part of the loop-condition. But all that is opinion based...

Comment: @alexandrahowes What makes you think it will skip ` trilist[c+1]` ?

Comment: The for loop is at index 5, array[5] must be deleted, therefore array[6] becomes array[5] and so on, when this is done, total is reduced by 1, the loop finishes and the loop is now at array[6] (which was 7 previously) so the old 6, now 5, is skipped!

Comment: @alexandrahowes No, not with the solutions above. First the loop will be executed with index 5 and  array[6]  is copied to array[5], array[7]  is copied to array[6] and so on. Then the loop is execute once more with index 5. So no elements are skipped.

Comment: @4386427, I was on my phone so somehow missed the alternative approach till now..! Am back at my PC now and will give it a go - very helpful!

Comment: @alexandrahowes The two examples will do the same.... which to prefer is opinion based

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you, I see now - how great to have such a helpful community of people ready to lend a hand. @4386427

Comment: @4386427 You are right. If the code is structured as a big `if`/`else`, then there is not much difference. If it is more complicated, then decrementing `i` inside the loop body might get confusing because (in contrast ot `total`) this changes not only the loop condition but also goes back to the previous array index or may even temporarily set the index to an invalid value (`-1`).